# Is consciousness considered a resolved/able problem?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, qualia

Is the existence of qualia generally considered an unresolved problem by philosophers? Is there a consensus on its nature or whether it can be studied at all?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. All philosophical problems are unresolved. This one is particularly controversial since it touches on the materialism/dualism divide current in the philosophy of mind. One does not need consensus to study a philosophical issue, for many of them the top approaches are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Conifold I'd consider that an answer :). But mainly, I read many pseudo explanations and am interested whether philosophers see them as such too

Comment: No it's not resolved, that's why its called 'The Big Problem' in science, and philosophy.proper. many people have answers.. nobody agrees.

Comment: @Conifold - I wish to argue., I see no justification for the statement that all philosophical problems are unresolved and would see it as highly unrigorous. I know of no unresolved problems. It would be accurate to say that not all philosophers agree that they have all been resolved, but we cannot prove they have not been resolved unless we can falsify all the proposed resolutions, and the one proposed by Lao Tsu is demonstrably unfalsifiable, It is therefore impossible to show that there are any unresolved philosophical problems.   .  .

Comment: @PeterJ That you admit philosophers consider them unresolved and disagree kind of makes the point. The test for acceptance of a thesis is not that it can not be refuted, in any context.

Comment: @Conifold - I would like to see you attempt to prove that metaphysical problems have never been resolved. The fact that that the professors of our universities consider them unresolved is hardly surprising given the scope of their studies. If the resolution to a problem works and is unfalsifiable it is at least plausible and it prevents us from stating that no resolution has been discovered. It becomes just a statement of your opinion. Better to say it is a matter of opinion whether metaphysical problems have been resolved. .  .

Comment: @PeterJ Asking someone to disprove your thesis is not a proper way to defend it. We know what consensus looks like, and how it is achieved, in math and science, and it is not there in art, religion or philosophy. Believing something really, really strongly, and demanding counterarguments does not change it.

Comment: @Conifold - I suppose you're bound to think I'm deluded. Belief is not necessary just an examination of the facts. In philosophy belief must give way to proof. I plan to stop commenting here because my views are too strong for the venue. It's time the philosophy department was closed down and the money put to better use. The idea that metaphysical problems cannot be resolved is ridiculous and should be dealt with in Metaphysics 101. The level of scholarship in professional;philosophy is a disgrace. Believing that metaphysics is intractable does not change the fact that it isn't.   . .

Comment: @PeterJ Don't get too frustrated, there are many things I think should be in the mainstream, but they are not. There are successful philosophical projects launched from outside of academia in recent times (Nietzsche, Popper, Chalmers), but they confirm the conclusion. Metaphysics, of any sort, just does not lend itself to commanding the kind of consent  we find in science and math. That is in the nature of its subject, which is far removed from pragmatic concerns, the same goes for art and religion.

Comment: @Conifold - You're welcome to your view but it would be ever so easy to show it is not justified, It requires ignoring logic and all the people who say metaphysics is comprehensible which is, of course, exactly what the people you mention do. Chalmers, for instance, wrote a long article on Idealism listing the various kinds, and fails to mention the only one that works. Philosophers of his ilk treat the word 'mysticism' much like the word 'Voldermort'. Apologies for venting my general frustration at you but sometimes the steam escapes. .      . . .

Comment: @Conifold - We shouldn't chat but I'll mention that my first dissertation was on this topic and in it I debunk your view. It has been read by a panel and subsequently by hundreds of people and In ten years has received not one objection. I'm not just waffling about some idiosyncratic view of philosophy. .

Comment: @PeterJ Think of it this way, most people use "debunk" and "opinion" differently, and until enough people are convinced there is no debunking, only an opinion. To change the common perception, one dissertation, or even a philosophical movement, aren't enough. But one can do blogs and podcasts these days, so the low profile of perennial metaphysics can not be blamed on academia alone. I doubt you'd agree with my assessment of what the problem is (we had a chat about that), but until the common usage changes we'll have to get along with it.

Comment: @Conifold - I don't think it is a matter of opinion that to call oneself a philosopher and not study one vast area of philosophy is idiotic. It is perfectly justifiable to blame such philosophers for the state of metaphysics. It is an academic scandal. If we won't look through the telescope then we cannot expect to understand astronomy. I can understand your view but do not share it. I may ask a question to explore the issues. I expect we'll keep crossing paths on this topic and will look forward to it. .    . . .   .

Comment: If you’re interested in new neuroscientific concepts, currently there’re several theories that seem to solve or partially solve this problem. Personally, I think the following theories have interesting concepts that can do this: [The Adaptive Resonance Theory](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0893-6080(16)30180-0), [The Basic Theory of the Mind](https://mindtheory.net), and [The Integrated Information Theory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4014402/pdf/pcbi.1003588.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Purely philosophically, consciousness is stuck between two schools of thought (generally, since each idea also have different sub-theories).

See more on the wikipedia article on [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness), especially the mind-body problem.

One is the materialist/realist idea, where consciousness is a product of cause and effect by random events dating back to the beginning of the universe with the big bang.

The other is the theist/deist/idealist idea, where consciousness is something beyond the physical, and has the power to influence our brain. Each school of thought presupposes something beyond the idea itself. Materialism presupposes that there is just matter and energy across time, and nothing beyond that. The converse presupposes that there exists some metaphysical higher plane outside of the purely physical, and that our mind/consciousness is either completely or partly residing within this higher plane, interacting with the physical plane.

The train of experiments that had it's outspringing in the original double-slit experiment seems to suggest that the mind is not only responsible for influencing the brain, but that it is quite literally responsible for manifesting it and the world around us. The mind might actually be more real than matter. In a way. [InspiringPhilosophy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4C5pq7W5yRM) on youtube has a video about this, where he goes through and explains the studies, with clips from interviews with experts.

I am not sure if the issue is resolved or not though. I think we are getting close.

Comment: Even in the Copenhagen interpretation, it is not being conscious that causes an observer to collapse a wavefunction when they make an observation. Mind can only be considered 'more real' from this in the sense of Wheeler's 'It From Bit' doctrine, that information is the fundamental monistic 'substance' and matter and other physics are emergent. I feel you distort the physics.

Comment: This is a difference in interpretation of the evidence. I (and by extension, IP) am not distorting anything. We just have a different presupposition. You say information, I say conscious mind. Actually, I say information FROM a conscious mind, you say ONLY information. We are taking the philosophical/metaphysical next step in connecting what (information) with where that what comes from (a conscious mind). Like IP says in the video, the train goes back to a conscious observer, so you can't scientifically prove that it is the information without us as conscious observers that collapses the fnc.

Comment: I didn't realise that this was seriously proposed https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann–Wigner_interpretation although as Sean Carol was saying recently it was never proposed in proper scientific terms, and this contributed to the bad reputation in academia of working onbfoundations of quantum mechanics https://youtu.be/AglOFx6eySE

Comment: I'm not surprised. I've already seen how academia can lock onto one or two ideas and locking everything else out as unscientific. Quantum physics, even though it is quite popular, it's still so early our understanding of it, so I will provide answers I find convincing.

Comment: 'Unscientific' means not susceptible to evaluation by evidence. If you prefer woo, fair enough, that's on you.

Comment: Semantically maybe, but realistically, the term unscientific is just as susceptible to corruption as anything. I recently saw "grammar of happiness", where the evaluation of evidence pointed towards Piraha being a language without recursion. Noam Chomsky and other researchers in his camp pretty much colored that as unscientific, even though the hard science provided evidence against him. Any theory or set of ideas are susceptible to a kind of religious adherence, even scientific ones.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. The 'science', anthropolgy and linguistic study, is not very hard, with only very few researchers able to work with so few speakers, and their bias being towards seeing them as exceptional. Hofstader's work suggests recursion is crucial to non-computational (incompleteness-limited) thought, ie creative rather than recursively enumarable from axioms. If Piraha is like this, sure it's big news. But saying physicists sceptical about faster than light neutrinos aren't scientific, would also be daft. Be open, but wary.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require the same amount of evidence as anything else. A claim that is supported by evidence is a claim that is supported by evidence, no matter its extraordinance. If you think the hard sciences are the only "real" sciences, that's an issue for another place, at least a different question to this.

To get back to the topic, the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment indicates that our conscious observance of which way the particle goes (the slit it enters) is what collapses the wave function. It removes the measurement as the reason.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me clarify... Problems that are 'resolved' disappear from philosophy, in the sense that they are no longer discussed or analyzed. Philosophy is an analytical process that aims to restructure the way we think about particular topics or issues; it resolves when we have come to some consensus about what structure that topic or issue should have. That 'disappearing' might take different forms...

- A Wittgensteinian therapy, where we realize that we have made a mistake in language and stop asking the question
- The establishment of a paradigm, where the question is *de facto* resolved, and collapses into dogma, practice, and/or technique
- A dialectical synthesis in which a philosophical question transforms into a different (deeper) philosophical question

... but the upshot is that the philosophical question itself stops being a pressing or relevant concern. It may return or it may not: some questions ebb and flow like the tides over the course of generations, others merely evaporate. But the point is that we only *philosophize* about things that are active problematics.

Qualia and subjectivity are currently an active problematic. There have been several efforts over the last century to make the problematic 'disappear,' usually by making 'subjectivity' an invalid construct in on sense or another (E.g., Skinnerism and Logical Positivism). But the issue kept arising, because it lies at the heart of both empiricist and rationalist philosophy. There are ongoing efforts to try to bridge the brain/mind barrier in various branches of psychology and neurology, and they've had some successes, but they are a long, long way from rendering this problem 'resolved' in any meaningful philosophical sense.

As to whether or not the philosophers believe the issue *can be* resolved... Well, philosophers clearly study it, so they clearly think — or at least hope — that some resolution is possible. Few people waste their time on causes they believe to be entirely hopeless. What that resolution might look like is anyone's guess; or rather, that is precisely the nature of the debate, and we cannot know the answer until the debate runs its course. But clearly (again) they see value in the debate itself, and keep trying different approaches to analyzing and studying the problem. That part of your question more or less answers itself.

Answer (score 0):

See https://qualiaresearchinstitute.org. It has very interesting things about this topic. But from just researching, it is *trying* to be resolved, but is still unresolved. Otherwise, I think *science* will help more with question than just pure philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which problem you're referring to, but if you're just asking whether there's general consensus on the nature or existence of consciousness, the answer is 'no'.

[Here's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/#QuaCha) an article from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy about the debates and academic research on consciousness up to the time the article was published. And [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/) is another one on qualia. These are summaries of the state of the academic conversation up to 2014 and 2017 respectively. So, as of 2014 and 2017 respectively, no—no consensus. If you have more specific questions about more specific problems involving consciousness or qualia, the articles are helpfully divided into subsections about those problems.

Answer (score 0):

The question is circular as you would have to be conscious of consciousness.  At best you could define and redefine it, but in doing so you are left in a continuum of a point of view.

At best consciousness is intrinsically empty, assumes patterns and reuses those patterns as means to keep reassuming.

The reason I say consciousness is intrinsically empty is that the term means such a variety of things to so many schools.

Lucretius, in "The Nature of Things" equivocated (in terms of antiquity) consciousness as atomic facts reorganized again and again into patterns.  Some reading into Wittgenstien could help, a little, but we are left with interpretations of interpretations  in considering the question of consciousness.

At best consciousness is connecting and separating variables which as assumed are inverted into new variables at which the process is repeated.  This ties in loosely Nietzches eternal reoccurrence with his perspectivism.

The problem is both resolved as defined and unresolved as open to further defintions.